# WKT: regex to extract only the first two floats values

Tags: regex

I have the input below:

```
LINESTRING(-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529,-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529)
```

and I need a regex that generates this:

```
-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529
```

Its essentially the first two floats.

Comment: Where does the input comes from ?

Comment: in which language?

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: It appears to be in WKT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

Comment: Just regex expression

Comment: It can be a general question of how to extract just the first K tokens that are matched.

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes! Great help to a genuine question that I know more than myself have.

Comment: There's a lot of regex engines, so when asking, please add all required informations.

Comment: Its for hive SQL regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=\()-?(:?[1-9]\d*|\d)(:?\.\d*)\s+-?(:?[1-9]\d*|\d)(:?\.\d*)(?=,)
```

**DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/Q2HreC/3

**Explanations and hypothesis:**

1. `(?<=\()` positive lookbehind to have the constraint that the floats follow a parenthesis
2. `-?(:?[1-9]\d*|\d)(:?\.\d*)` capture the first float: `-` is optional then a number with several digits starting by at least a 1, or a simple digit followed eventually by a `.` and some decimals.
3. `\s+` some spaces in the middle
4. followed by a second float
5. `(?=,)` positive look ahead to add the constraint followed by `,`

Comment: yes it does extract just `-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529`

Answer (score 0):

What about using the right tool for the right job ? This is a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) module to proper parse WKT :

### Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Geo::WKT::Simple;

my $arr = [];
push @{ $arr }, Geo::WKT::Simple::wkt_parse_linestring("LINESTRING(-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529,-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529)");
print join "\n", @{ $arr->[0] };
```

### Output :

```
-111.928130305897
33.4490602213529
```

### Doc :

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Geo-WKT/lib/Geo/WKT.pod

Answer (score 0):

To match the first 2 floats for your example, you might use:

[`^LINESTRING\(([-+]?\d*\.?\d+) ([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/eCHHaG/1)

That would match:

- `^LINESTRING` from the beginning of the string
- `\(` an opening parenthesis
- followed by matching a float `([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)` 2 times in a capturing group

The float regex:

```
(       # Capturing group
  [-+]? # Optional + or -
  \d*   # Match a digits zero or more times
  \.?   # Optional dot
  \d+   # Match a digit one or more times
)       # Close capturing group
```

Or to match `-111.928130305897 33.4490602213529` for your example
 without capturing groups you could use:

[`(?<=^LINESTRING\()[-+]?\d*\.?\d+ [-+]?\d*\.?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/eCHHaG/2)

or

[`(?<=^LINESTRING\()[^,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/eCHHaG/3)